# Uber API console or postman file?

Tags: uber-api

Do you know if online API console for uber exist, so we can try their API calls using it (or a postman collection as alternative?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that I know of. I usually use curl

Comment: @DmitrySemenov cURL is fine but maybe you prefer a more user friendly HTTP client, in that case I recommend: [HTTPie: a CLI, cURL-like tool for humans](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie#httpie-a-cli-curl-like-tool-for-humans)

Comment: I have made some api's postman call. link:- [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_R6zxmEjJYjcm5ySnJuU0NUSTQ/view?usp=sharing)